# Excel VBA equivalent of ADDRESS function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to write this function in vba so that it gives me the cell id.

`=ADDRESS(1,2,4,TRUE,"Sheet1")`

Does anyone know the VBA syntax for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=Workshsheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,2).Address(0,0,xlA1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal way to do a similar thing in VBA would be either

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, _
                                         ColumnAbsolute:=False, _
                                         External:=True)
```

which would return `[TestWorkbook.xlsm]Sheet1!B1` or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, _
                                         ColumnAbsolute:=False, _
                                         External:=False)
```

which would just return `B1`.

There isn't a simple way of showing the worksheet name and cell, without also including the workbook name.  A possible way would be

```
"'" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Name & "'!" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, _
                                                                                  ColumnAbsolute:=False, _
                                                                                  External:=False)
```

(Obviously, if you use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Name` then you may as well just use `"Sheet1"`, but I wrote it that way so that you could use a variable instead of a hardcoded value.  Edit: On rereading that last sentence, I realise how stupid it is - `Worksheets(mySheetName).Name` is the same as `mySheetName`, so just use `"'" & mySheetName & "'!" & ...`)